# Is the result of my translation grammatically correct?

Tags: clauses, commas, time

I was trying to translate a sentence from German to English and would like to know if the result is grammatically correct.

> I agree explicitly that you start before the end of the cancellation period with the execution of the contract. I am aware that with the start of execution of the contract I’m losing my right of cancellation.

Comment: This looks like it's intended as language for use in a legal instrument. In legal contexts English expressions often have very specific meanings which they do not have in ordinary discourse. I don't think ELL can give legal advice; in many jurisdictions where our Answerers are active it is illegal for anyone but an attorney to do so.

Comment: @StoneyB good point and +1.  I'd like to stress to the OP, though, that two people don't need an attorney to enter into a contract.  In other words, you can't void a contract because an attorney didn't help to write it.

Comment: @BobRodes Quite so; but holding yourself out as an 'expert' on legal language exposes you to the Awful Majesty of the Legal Profession.

Comment: @StoneyB I understand your point and you're right, it's the text of a checkbox - which the user has to click if he wants to order something. In the Terms & Conditions of that website, it's also clearly mentioned that the binding language of the contract is German and that all other texts are "just" translations. To make it clear, I'm not looking for any legal advice and do not consider any answer as such. I'm just trying to find out if I did some grammatically mistakes within that text or not.

Comment: @StoneyB Absolutely.  See my answer below.  My concern is that I have heard people say things like "this was only a verbal contract so it isn't binding" or "we just did it on a napkin, no attorney looked at it so it isn't really binding" and things like that.

Comment: @Teo: you may find that that isn't enough.  If someone can reasonably be expected not to understand the language of a contract into which he enters, then the translation can be held to be binding over the original language of the contract.  I would also consult a lawyer on this one.

Comment: RE: *it's the text of a checkbox - which the user has to click if he wants to order something*. I don't know why O.P.'s are so reluctant to share such information until after the questions start pouring in. Confound it all! Why didn't you include that information from the start? Don't you see how that context could have made things clearer for everyone from the outset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I would say "I agree explicitly that you *will* start..." The rest looks fine from a purely grammatical standpoint.

However, as StoneyB has said, this sounds like a legal instrument.  I would certainly get legal advice before entering into this agreement.

It doesn't take a lawyer (and I'm not one) to see some things here that could get you into trouble.  First, it doesn't say anything about whether the other party agrees that he will start before the end of the cancellation period.  It only says that you agree to this.  So, someone could argue (maybe not successfully, but you don't want to leave the possibility open) that the other party could start executing the job after the cancellation date, and that if he did so, you would lose your right of cancellation. Then, it also doesn't say anything about how long the other party has to do whatever job it refers to.

So you're possibly agreeing to allow the other party to start whenever he wants, take as long as he wants, prevent you from getting anyone else to do the job in his place, and compel you to pay for it whenever he gets around to finishing it.  I wouldn't advise that from a common sense perspective.

In other words, it might be a good idea to find a lawyer.  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and I appreciate your comment. Since I didn't expect so much concern about the content rather than the grammar of the text, I didn't think it would be necessarily to mentioned more about the source of that text. But since it came up here some further info about the text: This is just a very small part of legal texts which were prepared by a lawyer! :) The mentioned text is the text of a checkbox. There are two more checkboxes - with all  required links (Terms / Privacy Policy / Cancellation Policy). So nothing to worry :) Thanks again for your answer! +1

Comment: You're very welcome, but please see my comment above as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a lawyer and the following is not legal advice.

I think there's some grammatical tense issues as well as possibly major issues with some of the semantics.

**Original:**

- (1)
- I agree explicitly  ("explicitly" not needed: an agreement is an agreement)
- that you start
- before the end of the cancellation period
- with the execution of the contract.
  .
- (2)
- I am aware that  (Contracts are not about awareness, they are about terms. Awareness is not necessarily a term, and thus may not be binding to anything other than the awareness itself!)
- with the start of
- execution of the contract
- I’m losing my right of cancellation.

**Interpretation of what is actually being said:**

- (1) SUBSCRIBER agrees that the execution of this contract will begin before the end of the cancellation period.
- (2) Upon contract execution, SUBSCRIBER waives the right to cancel this contract.

Another possible problem is that a "contract" is typically executed upon signature or acceptance, so it seems to me that there may be some strange concept of contract here.  Unless you think that there are **two contracts**, one of which is this agreement-about-the-other-contract.  If it's something that is a "common type of thing" on the Internet, it wouldn't hurt to do a "sanity check" by looking at how other contracts are worded.

You might want to do this again with some other English speaking website.  What I've done is **try to interpret what you mean** and it was very difficult.  So what good is it if a native speaker cannot understand exactly what you mean?

You might want to get another lawyer to check the first one.

You might want someone to translate your English back to German and see if you get the same thing.

Just some ideas...